# How to determine whether some string is in the list or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var name_list = ['Annie','John','Lyam','Mary']

var text_be_checked_1 = 'Annie'
do_some_stuff(name_list, text_be_checked_1) // true

var text_be_checked_2 = 'Ann'
do_some_stuff(name_list, text_be_checked_2) // false

var text_be_checked_3 = '1Annie'
do_some_stuff(name_list, text_be_checked_3) // true

var text_be_checked_4 = 'An2nie'
do_some_stuff(name_list, text_be_checked_4) // false

var text_be_checked_5 = 'Anni_John'
do_some_stuff(name_list, text_be_checked_5) // true
```

What I want is that determining whether text has full match with name in `name_list` like above.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript), but this is not exactly what I need.

How can I do this?

I don't care about where the solution came from. javascript or jQuery are all okay.

Would you solve this please?

**EDIT:**

Thank you everyone, There are many answers and I tested them.

But I thought that I have to add more explanation of my question.

You have to check this:

```
var name_list = ['Annie','John','Lyam','Mary']

var text_be_checked_3 = '1Annie'
do_some_stuff(name_list, text_be_checked_3) // true
```

As your answers, from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_includes_array)
`Mango` can return true, but `1Mango`, `Mango_to` returns false.

This is point, What I want is that `1Mango` and `Mango_to` are also return true.

If this explanation is not enough, please comment me.

Comment: it seems the same to me.
Can you explain why its different?

Comment: I think you were misunderstood. Try this

    function inArray(needle, haystack) {
        var length = haystack.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            return needle.indexOf(haystack[i])!==-1 ;
        }
        return false;
    }

    var name_list = ['Annie','John','Lyam','Mary'];

    var output=inArray('1Annie', name_list);
    console.log(output);

Comment: you cannot im afraid. But glad i could help. @barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Below Code as per your need it works :

```js
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var name_list = ['Annie','John','Lyam','Mary'];

var output=inArray('Annie', name_list);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: yeah, or `haystack.includes(needle)`, but why make things simple :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function do_some_stuff(list, str) {
    return list.indexOf(str) !== -1
}
```

It is really that simple.

`Array.indexOf()` returns -1 if the item you are checking is not in the array. So by comparing the returned value to -1, you get a `true` if the item is in the list, and a `false` if it is not in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by simply doing:
`if (name_list.includes(text_to_be_checked) ) {}`

Take your time to check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should link to the English documentation.

Comment: yep I'm sorry I fixed it

Comment: NO!!!! French MDN is still better than w3fools.

Comment: Yep I know but the explanation is still correct ^^

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach:

`name_list.filter(word => word == text_be_checked_1).length >= 1`

Comment: yeah, or `name_list.includes(text_be_checked_1)`, but why make things simple :)

Comment: because this solution has already been mentioned.. why write it twice?

Comment: Your `.filter` is not only more complicated to read, it's also way less efficient. It will filter the _whole_ array, even if the element is found at position 2 and the array contains 1000 elements. `.includes` will stop at 2.

Comment: Did he ask for the most efficient solution or for A solution? I never said my solution is better than any but it works and can be applied to almost any language that supports functional programming

Answer (score 1):

`name_list.some(name => name=== 'Mike')` would return **false**

`name_list.some(name => name=== 'Annie')` would return **true** in your case.

The array method some returns true or false based on a condition. You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're actually looking for i guess,

```js
var name_list = ['Annie','John','Lyam','Mary']

var text_be_checked_1 = 'Annie'

if($.inArray(text_be_checked_1, name_list) !== -1){
  console.log('value exist');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will helpful to you!

Greetings!

Comment: Load an entire library just to replace a native `name_list.includes(text_be_checked_1)`? No thank you